# How to implement a glass effect created on PS-CS4 around the template using PNG?

Tags: html, css, png, effect, aero-glass

Hi as I said some times before I'm new to CSS coding, I want to know if it is possible to create a glass sheet (vista/seven like but without the buttons) around the template using only CSS, I know how to make rounded corners:

```
    <style type="text/css">
    #box {

      position: relative;
      width: 100px;
    }
      .corner {
        background: url('http://www.wreckedclothing.net/images/corners.gif') no-repeat 0 0; /* img from google */
        display: block;
        height: 10px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 10px;
      }
      .tl { top: 0; left: 0; background-position: 0 0; }
      .tr { top: 0; right: 0; background-position: -22px 0; }
      .bl { bottom: 0; left: 0; background-position: 0 -22px; }
      .br { bottom: 0; right: 0; background-position: -22px -22px; }

      .content {padding:10px;}

    </style>

    <div id="box">
      <div class="corner tl"><!-- --></div>
      <div class="corner tr"><!-- --></div>
      <div class="corner bl"><!-- --></div>
      <div class="corner br"><!-- --></div>
      <div class="content">the name of jeremiah is jorge gonzaga I have no Idea where this came from!</div>
    </div>
```

I already have the graphics created on photoshop and sliced

ex taken from answer here, but how do I make for example a div stick to the left and auto expand till the bottom with some margin on it? or is that an easier way? I just don't want to use tables or even worst JS (don't know how to use this language yet)...

Any answer will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

3 divs containing background images.
cut the image into 3 parts. top mid and bottom.
top one has top glass. and bottom has bottom glass.
and repeat-y the middle one. and put contents in the middle div.

Comment: I did that once, of course it worked but the PNG get twice the size with transparence on both left and right side, even a 1px image get extra large to consider using uless that is no other way! the truth is the main problem is the content area... the top and the bottom can be easily solved!

Comment: what. how do you cut your png? they are not much bigger or sometimes even smaller than their jpeg counterpart. the top and bottom need to be as tall as they need to. but the mid section only need to be 1px height.

Comment: that is what I did, but when you add transparence to png they use 24 bits color depth, that can enhance the size of the file quite a bit! By the way I slice it using photoshop CS4 slice tool